# Cloth Simulation : Self collision results in cloth "exploding"

Tags: modeling, mesh, particles, physics, cloth-simulation

I'm trying to model a cotton garment by simulating it's draping process. I'm having issues only when I enable self-collision of the cloth. Without self-collision , there are no issues but I do need self-collision for later stages of work and can't proceed without enabling that. I'm using 2.73, and I didn't modify any settings; that is , I use the default collision settings and for everything else too. Below are screenshots of the issue.

***Rest state:***

[image]

**End result, without collision, close to what I want; but as seen, cloth is penetrating itself:**

[image]

***When I enable self-collision, this happens right from the 1st frame itself:***

[image]

**The end result is also similarly messed up.**

***These are my cloth settings:***
[image]

I believe that the simulation is finding the cloth particles close together and hence repelling them from each other, given the messed up result. I set the "distance" value in the collision settings to 0.5 and 1 too, but both of them gave the same result.. Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: In your screenshot Blender states, that the cache is outdated. The first thing i'd try is to clear the cache (e.g. set frame to 1).

Comment: Have you tried bringing down the self collision Distance value?

Comment: Yes, I tried 0.5 as well..same thing..

Comment: Apply rotation and scale. Just got same problem.

Comment: @PiotrJędrzejko Didn't get you exactly...rotate and scale what?

Comment: I know this is very late but the order of your modifiers is in blender collision should at least come before the physics so try changing the order of the modifiers

Comment: @sanjeevmk See [this post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation) on applying transforms.

Answer (score 1):

A POSSIBLE WORK AROUND (that at least worked for me):

Scale up everything, then apply the transformation (CTRL+A > all transforms)

Sometimes cloth simulations in Blender results in error with too small meshes.

Hope this may help.

G

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how the setting relates to measurement, but I believe your self-collision distance is way too large. I believe the numbers relate to 'real-world' or blender units, so you need to make sure if you have a dense mesh, that the self-collsion distance is smaller than the closest vertices you want in the simulation. Often I'll set this somewhere around .05 or even much smaller e.g. .001. The cloth engine has also changed a fair bit since this question, but maybe this will shed some light for someone.
EDIT: yes it seems the newer cloth refactor by Luca Rood calculates collisions in real units, therefore the distances need to be pretty small.